# Django models don't work with Oracle database

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

I have several apps with different database connections. They all work fine.
My new app needs an Oracle connection, which is set up in the `settings.py`:

```
'database_oracle' : {
        'ENGINE'   : 'oracle',
        'NAME'     : 'name',
        'USER'     : 'user',
        'PASSWORD' : 'pw',
        'HOST'     : 'connection',
        'PORT'     :  1234,
        'SCHMEA'   :  'abc',
    },
```

The models in my `models.py` have additional meta classes:

```
 class Meta:
    db_table = '"abc.table1"'
    data_source = 'database_oracle'
    data_source_app = 'myapp'
```

The problem is that

```
Model1.objects.all()
```

returns an error: `

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

But if I use the `django.db` connection:

```
from django.db import connections
db_conn = connections['database_oracle']
c = db_conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT MAX(date) FROM abc.table1 WHERE key = 1234567").fetchall()
```

It works perfectly fine.
So I tried different spellings for db_table:

1. db_table = 'table1'
2. db_table = '"table1"'
3. db_table = 'abc.table1'
4. db_table = '"abc.table1"'

Changes were migrtated every time and this is how my `routers.py` look like (the if-statements belong to other apps and other databases):

```
myapps = ['myapp']
class DataRouter:
  def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if [...]
    elif model._meta.app_label in myapps:
        return 'database_oracle'
    return None
  def db_for_write(self,model, **hints):
    if [...]
    elif model._meta.app_label in myapps:
        return 'database_oracle'
    return None
  def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if [...]
    elif obj1._meta.app_label in myapps or obj2._meta.app_label in myapps:
        return True
    return None
  def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if [...]
    elif app_label in myapps:
        return db =='database_oracle'
    return None
```

Does anyone have any idea why the models can't connect to my database?

Comment: did you tried ```Model1.objects.using("database_oracle").all()```?

Comment: also try to remove unnecessary double quotes from ```db_table = '"abc.table1"'``` in ```Meta``` class

Comment: @dorintufar thanks so far and yes, I tried it but the Traceback is still the same. And I tried the double quotes as Django suggests to use them for oracle dbs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/

Comment: You've tried `db_table = '"abc"."table1"'`?

Comment: @WillKeeling that was the answer :). Thanks so much!